# Strip brackets before writing to csv using writerow

Tags: python

```
def write_to_csv(file_name, header, numpy_data):
    with open(file_name, "w", newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        header = [header]
        for line in header:
            writer.writerow(line)

        for line in numpy_data:
            if line is None:
                writer.writerow(line)
            else:
                writer.writerow(line)
```

I have cells in my excel like this after executing the above code

```
['Financial Analysis', 'Finance', 'Financial Modeling']
```

What I would like is

```
Financial Analysis, Finance, Financial Modeling
```

I tried to do `line.strip("[]")` but then nothing appears in the excel when I do this.

sample of `numpy_data` is :

```
[['Financial Analysis', 'Finance', 'Financial Modeling']]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def write_to_csv(file_name, header, numpy_data):
    with open(file_name, "w", newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        header = [header]
        for line in header:
            writer.writerow(line)

        for line in numpy_data:
            if line is None:
                writer.writerow(line)
            else:
                val = [", ".join(line[0])] + line[1:]  #--> ['Financial Analysis, Finance, Financial Modelling', '5000', 'Company A']
                writer.writerow(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand the row from the numpy data use `*` like:

#### Code:

```
writer.writerow(*line)
```

#### Whole Listing:

```
def write_to_csv(file_name, header, numpy_data):
    with open(file_name, "w", newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(header)
        for line in numpy_data:
            if line is None:
                writer.writerow(line)
            else:
                writer.writerow(*line)
```

Comment: Hi I tried your way but it is still empty. I am passing in the argument numpy_data as [ [ ['Financial Analysis', 'Finance', 'Financial Modelling'], '5000', 'Company A' ],  [ ['Programming', 'Critical Thinking', 'Problem Solving'], '4000', 'Company B'] ] for example. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using a join statement in a list comprehension that identifies instances of lists and converts them to strings before writing the list of elements to file.

```
line = [', '.join(i) if isinstance(i,list) else i for i in line]
writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Hi I did this but still got empty excel. writer.writerow(''.join(line))

Comment: I see on another comment that you gave the example: [ [ ['Financial Analysis', 'Finance', 'Financial Modelling'], '5000', 'Company A' ], [ ['Programming', 'Critical Thinking', 'Problem Solving'], '4000', 'Company B'] ].
How will the output in the csv look once processed?

Comment: Hi the output will look like this. In cell B2 -> ['Financial Analysis', 'Finance', 'Financial Modelling']. In cell C2 -> 5000. In cell D2 -> Company A. Basically, the cells will contain the brackets which i do not want. thanks

Comment: In order for this to work, the line written the csv file has to look like this: "Financial Analysis, Finance, Financial Modelling",5000,Company A. Otherwise the csv will not be able to correctly parse it. (I'll update my answer shortly)

Comment: I've made the appropriate update to my answer. Like I said before, we will want to use a join statement. The code I gave joins each instance of a list into a string before passing it to the csv writer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv, codecs, cStringIO
import threading


class UnicodeWriter:

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()
        self.lock = threading.RLock()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)
        self.lock.release()

    def writerows(self, rows):
        self.lock.acquire()
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)
        self.stream.flush()
        self.lock.release()
```

And in your file , import this above file, like:

```
def write_to_csv(file_name, header, numpy_data):
    with open(file_name, "w", newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        header = [header]
        for line in header:
            writer.UnicodeWriter(line)

        for line in numpy_data:
            if line is None:
                writer.UnicodeWriter(line)
            else:
                writer.UnicodeWriter(line)
```